# What is the best way to run protractor to test my AngularJS app that was developed on VS2013 Ultimate?

Tags: angularjs

From what I understand the recommended tool to run E2E tests for an AngularJS SPA application is now Protractor.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate for all of my development on a Windows 7 OS. Can someone explain to me how I could best run my protractor tests? Is there a way I can run these from inside of VS2013 or should I load up some other software to run the tests.

Also does anyone have any good links that could point me to where I could get some good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of articles about this. Here are a few that will help you get it setup and a video that demonstrates and teaches some usage.

Setup: 
http://www.theroks.com/running-e2e-tests-angularjs-based-applications-protractor/
http://misaxionsoftware.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/angularjs-protractor-visual-studio-super-dry/

How to use: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2014/02/17/writing-e-2-e-tests-for-angularjs-using-protractor.aspx